# ' scandir ' или ' xml / sql / csv ' список файлов?

Tags: файлы, php, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток гуру! Будте добры, подскажите как сделать логичнее...
Есть несложная структура папок в которой хранятся изображения, нужно их выводить.

- **Как сделать логичнее: scandir или xml/sql/csv список изображений и из него выбирать?**
- **Выбирать, сортировать, и тд ничего не нужно поэтому не хочу заморотов с базой насколько медленне скандир чем вывод из списка?**
- @ **Нужно готовить только превьюшки, ресайз сделал, но он пишет в файл, есть ли способ делать ресайз на лету? (прошу прощение за глупый вопрос)**

*p.s. ах да, мне предпочтительнее скандиром, насколько это "косячно"?*

или может быть логичнее сделать чтото типа file_scan.php который отсканирует все директории, создаст превьюшки, и всё как положено гладко отправит в базу а потом уже черпать запросами базу а не сканить жесткие диски сервака?

Comment: Последний вариант мне больше нравится :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, очередной вопрос на тему преждевременной оптимизации. Правильный ответ: попробуйте разные варианты, отпрофилируйте, причём не в "чистом коде", а на своём месте в полном цикле вашего приложения. Это касается не только быстродействия и ресурсозатратности, но и вписывания в общую логику программы, качества сопровождения кода, переносимости и всего остального. За вас всё равно никто думать не будет, учитесь это делать самостоятельно.

Comment: Я лишь спрашиваю вашего мнения, к примеру, в коде старюсь совсем не использовать goto, как можно меньше for, if вместе с ifesle (прдпочтительнее switch). Как вы считаете логично ли использовать scandir в коде?

Comment: Я понятия не имею, какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово "логично", поэтому на такой сложный вопрос ответить не могу. Ваш код - вам и видней, что в нём логично, а что нет.